# App store blocks my application (ionic cordova ios 6.0)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, uiwebview

I am working on an application started in April and refused by the app store.

I took over the project yesterday, I deleted platform ios and I installed the latest version (6.0)

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/01/cordova-ios-release-6.0.0.html

However, while version 6.0 is supposed to stop using UiWebView, I get this error message when I try to send the app to the Apple store connect

"ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview)."

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "X",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/app-rate": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/badge": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/base64": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/calendar": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/clipboard": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/crop": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/stripe": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.11.10",
    "aios": "0.2.3",
    "call-number": "1.0.1",
    "com-badrit-base64": "0.2.0",
    "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "1.2.5",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-clipboard": "1.3.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-apprate": "1.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-calendar": "5.1.5",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-crop": "0.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "1.7.4",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "6.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "5.6.8",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^6.6.2",
    "ngx-qrcode2": "0.0.9",
    "ngx-qrcode3": "^0.3.0",
    "ngx-stripe": "^7.4.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.13.0",
    "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "5.0.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "^5.4.4",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": {
        "GOOGLE_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "X",
        "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.12.0",
        "LOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires access to your location for navigation purposes"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-badge": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
      "cordova-clipboard": {},
      "com-badrit-base64": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-calendar": {
        "CALENDAR_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
        "CONTACTS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "X",
        "APP_NAME": "X"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-apprate": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.1+",
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires photo library access to function properly.",
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires photo library access to function properly."
      },
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "cordova-plugin-crop": {},
      "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

If someone has an idea.
Thanks in advance.
Cordially.

Comment: Do you have any plugins that would use the uiwebkit ? try updating your plugin and if that fails, create a new app and copy the code over there.

Comment: Do you know how I can verify this?

The concern is that it is a very large application, and I am afraid that starting a project again at 0 will take time (even by making copy / paste)

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Make sure all the cordova plugins you are using are up to date. I am not aware of any automatic way to finding out. You could also a project wide search.

Comment: I have updated all cordova plugins, and I still have the same concerns ...

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my app for the exact issue recently. Since you have updated all the packages to the latest versions, I would suggest you to directly jump tp the 4th step below.

For others, Here are the steps to fix the issue:

1) Ensure your `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` is updated to the latest version `5.0.0`. You need to run these two commands to do that.

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest
```

2) Ensure your `cordova-ios` is updated to the latest version `6.0.0`. Run this command to update it.

```
npm install cordova-ios@latest --save
```

3) Check your `package.json` to see if the versions are updated for both `cordova-ios` and `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview`.

4) Ensure you add `WKWebViewOnly` preference to `config.xml` file.

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    ...
</platform>
```

5) This is the most important step. Ensure you remove the `ios` platform and add it again. Run these commands to remove and add the `ios` platform.

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Now, when you build the ios app and publish it to the app store, you can see the issue will be fixed.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your message

I did all the steps, but the apple store still refuses my app

Comment: Can you share the list of the Cordova packages in your ionic application?

Comment: I put my package.json in the initial post. Thank you

Comment: Looks like inAppBrowswer is one more plugin which might be using UIWebView, Can you try updating it to the latest version?

Comment: Same problem with last version of plugin inAppBrowser :(

Comment: Can you remove the `ios` folder inside the `platforms` folder and also remove `ios` from `platforms` in `package.json` file?
After removing those, run the command `ionic cordova build ios` and see if it working?

Comment: And also can you manually check all the versions of the plugins inside `plugins` folder?
If the version does not match the version mentioned in your base `package.json`, you might have to reinstall the plugin properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command and check which plugin is including reference to UIWebView.

grep -r "UIWebView" .

Then, you can try to remove all those references before compiling.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` & `cordova-sms-plugin` to get this working. It seems like they both use UIWebView modules.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it with these steps:

- Added cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr@3.0.0
- Added cordova-plugin-nativestorage-2.3.2
- Updated cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@4.0.0
- Updated cordova-plugin-splashscreen@6.0.0.
- Used cordova-ios@6.2.0.

I removed:

```
    <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
    <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```

from my config.xml

Source: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/883